# How does the forEach function work under the hood in Swift

Tags: swift3

Please note this question is NOT about "How to use forEach method on an instance of type Array". As apple points out [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689783-foreach#discussion) forEach calls the supplied closure for each value present inside the array.

My question is:

```
1. How does forEach method gets each value present inside the array? 
2. I tried finding the source code for it with no luck.
```

Comment: You can take a look for yourself: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L1053

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for pointing out. I am not able to get what's going in that code specially this part "for element in self { try body(element)    }" Could you please explain it?

Comment: What part exactly don't you get? The `for` loop iterates over the elements of the sequence, applying the `body` function to each element. Because the `body` function can throw, it's preceded by a `try`, allowing thrown errors to be re-thrown back to the caller.

Comment: Two parts : first one:  "for element in self ". self is holding the reference to the instance of type array. Correct? Now under the hood how exactly is this iteration working? this instance (pointed by self) could have any other variables in it, how exactly does logic for for loop know which variable/list to iterate over.   Second part : body function, what is that supposed to do here? Is there any easy way to find these function on the Swift github repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foreach uses a for in loop, which uses a Sequence Iterator.  The apple documentation for [IteratorProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol) outlines how it works (basically its a while iterator.next() loop).  You may also want to look at [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence).  [Advanced Swift](https://www.objc.io/books/advanced-swift/) is worth owning if you are interested in this sort of thing.